# JpaRepository unable to find property

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, couchbase

I've just upgraded my project to Spring Boot 2 and getting this error now with one of my JpaRepositories:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAll found for type UserOrder
```

My UserOrderRepository looks like this:

```
@Repository
public interface UserOrderRepository extends JpaRepository<UserOrder, String> {

}
```

Absolutely no where in my code am I using the word `findAll`. Not as a property, not as a method, so completely lost as to why I'm getting this error.

This project is writing to Couchbase using the Spring framework spring-data-couchbase artifact.

running the command line mvn dependency:tree | grep -i spring gives:

```
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-couchbase:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-properties-migrator:jar:2.0.1.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.0.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-metadata:jar:2.0.1.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.0.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.0.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.0.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.0.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.0.1.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.0.1.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.1.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.0.5.RELEASE:test
```

Comment: Can you share the full stacktrace?

Comment: Please post your POM/Gradle file. This smells like you have incompatible versions of Spring Data dependencies. (`findAll` is implicitly declared in a superinterface, and the repository system has to provide a method definition at runtime.)

Comment: @chrylis - I thought about that. Besides Spring Boot 2, my POM file only points to other internal applications. I have instead shown my dependency tree as I thought that might be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue in the past. I don't remember exactly what was the issue but it was somewhere related to return type of a repository method. From our custom JPARepository in one of the method, we were returning DTO instead of an ENTITY object.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a couple of days on this, I was unable to figure out why I was getting this error. I was able to work around it by changing the commented out code to save one at a time. Also this may be a specific problem related to the Spring Couchbase data project.

```
public boolean upsertUserOrders(Set<UserOrder> userOrderSet) {
    //userOrderRepository.save(userOrderSet);
    userOrderSet.forEach(uo -> userOrderRepository.save(uo));
}
```

I know this is not idea but figured I would post my solution (until a real solution gets posted) in case anyone else runs into this issue.